# pip upgrade TooManyRedirects exception

Tags: docker, redirect, pip, upgrade

I'm trying to `pip install --upgrade pip` inside a docker container, however, I get the error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 842, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 597, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 113, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects)
TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this is, and/or how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A redirect is issued by the server to the `pip` client. Assuming you're using the default PyPI and not a proxy, the first place to check is the Python status page at [status.python.org](https://status.python.org/).

This was recently posted:

> Update - We are currently investigating redirect loops for some package installs.
>
> Apr 16, 15:22 UTC

And this even more recently:

> Update - We've rolled out a fix for the redirect issue on files.pythonhosted.org for the new PyPI and are monitoring.
>
> Apr 16, 15:35 UTC

Comment: I am now getting 404 errors from PyPi..
Which is also on their status now.