# python3.6 -m virtualenv test_me fails error 400

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am having some trouble executing this python command.
Previously, this didn't happen and I can't figure out what's wrong or missing.

```
Tests-MacBook-Pro:virtualenvs testytester$ python3.6 -m virtualenv ga2
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in /Users/testytester/virtualenvs/ga2/bin/python3.6
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/testytester/virtualenvs/ga2/bin/python (you must use /Users/testytester/virtualenvs/ga2/bin/python3.6)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/testytester/...vs/ga2/bin/python3.6 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
  HTTP error 400 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8010754433e3211b9cdbbf784b50f30e80bf40fc6b05eb5f865fab83300599b8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*)
  Could not install requirement setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8010754433e3211b9cdbbf784b50f30e80bf40fc6b05eb5f865fab83300599b8 because of error 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install requirement setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8010754433e3211b9cdbbf784b50f30e80bf40fc6b05eb5f865fab83300599b8 because of HTTP error 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl for URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/d7/04a0b689d3035143e2ff288f4b9ee4bf6ed80585cc121c90bfd85a1a8c2e/setuptools-39.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8010754433e3211b9cdbbf784b50f30e80bf40fc6b05eb5f865fab83300599b8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*)
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/testytester/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/testytester/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/testytester/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Users/testytester/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Users/testytester/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/testytester/...vs/ga2/bin/python3.6 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip upgrade TooManyRedirects exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860980/pip-upgrade-toomanyredirects-exception)

Comment: The error is different but the cause is the same — PyPI is rolling out a new infrastracture and redirects pypi.python.org to pypi.org.