# `TooManyRedirects` with `pipenv lock` and `pipenv install`

Tags: python, pipenv

An exception is being raised for `pipenv lock` and `pipenv install` commands which indicates that too many requests are being performed.

```
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 617, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 617, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 110, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects, response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Related:

- [pip upgrade TooManyRedirects exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860980/pip-upgrade-toomanyredirects-exception)
- [python3.6 -m virtualenv test_me fails error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862266/python3-6-m-virtualenv-test-me-fails-error-400)

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a `[[source]]` URL, you need to change it from `https://pypi.python.org/simple` to `https://pypi.org/simple`.

E.g.:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"
```